# Comparison of matrix determinant in less than $O(n^2)$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, linear-algebra

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249768/verifying-whether-a-number-is-the-determinant-of-a-matrix?noredirect=1#comment2539912_1249768) question and I think maybe somebody here could help.

This is the idea: Given a matrix $M$ of integers, and a number $d$ is there a way to compare the **determinant** of $M$ and $d$ in a fast way? Note that we don't need the calculation of the determinant, only comparison.

The motivation is this: if one could find a good (maybe less than $O(n^2)$) algorithm, and with an upper and lower bounds for the determinant, one could perform binary (or linear?, no, I don't think so) search over the interval in order to determine the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: What do you mean with comparing $M$ and $d$? Maybe I'm not trying hard enough, but do you mean you are comparing some value $d$ against every value in a matrix $M$?

Comment: @Juho I mean comparing the determinant of $M$ and $d$

Comment: An adversary argument should show that you need to look at all entries, and this gives an $\Omega(n^2)$ lower bound.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes, but suppose that we have known bounds for the determinant and/or for the values of $M$, the idea of the question is if is there an approach, maybe with some restrictions of course. I just put the motivation as an example, but the question is still valid, maybe just to find the fastest way for the comparison.

Comment: It is also known that computing the determinant exactly in the algebraic computation model (so no IFs) takes time $\tilde{O}(n^\omega)$, where $\omega$ is the exponent of matrix multiplication. Your algorithm has IFs, but they are not supposed to help. For concreteness, imagine that you are computing the determinant over $GL(2)$. In this setting, binary search doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: As far as I know the only way you can reason about the determinant in this way is if you know $M$ satisfies certain properties.  For example, check out this paper ("Upper Bounds for the Determinant of a row Stochastic Matrix"): http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/70B/jresv70Bn2p157_A1b.pdf

Comment: So, maybe the short answer is simply that you need to calculate the determinant in order to perform the comparison? And there is no $O(n^2)$ approach.